# $(window).load after $(document).ajaxComplete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function that is working correctly on page load:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    OnloadFunction();
});
```

Although when I rerun the query via ajax and load in the new content, OnloadFunction does not work.

```
$('.submenu li').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var sortSelect = $(this).find('div').text();
      var categorySelect = $(this).parent().attr('class').replace('submenu ', '');
        $('.all-songs').html('<h2 class="result">Loading...</h2>');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'text',
        url: sortAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: 'my_ajax_sort',
            categorySelect: categorySelect,
            sortSelect: sortSelect
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('.all-songs').html(response);
        }
      })
   });
```

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    OnloadFunction();

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
            OnloadFunction();
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        OnloadFunction();
    });
});
```

ajax updated Html is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
     xxxxxx
  });
});
```

Here is the function that needs to run:

```
function OnloadFunction () {

        $('.sc-trackslist li').each(function() {
            var trackNum = $(this).index();
            var top = trackNum * 50 + trackNum * 1;
            $(this).css('top', top);
        });

        $('.sc-trackslist > li').click(function () {
        if ($('.sc-play').hasClass('clicked') || $('.sc-pause').hasClass('clicked')) {

        } else {
            $('.sc-play').addClass('hidden');
            $('.sc-pause').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.sc-player .sc-info, .sc-player .sc-scrubber, .sc-player .sc-controls').slideDown(200);
            $('#footer').css('margin-bottom', '90px');
        }
        });

        $('.sc-trackslist > li').hover(function() {
            var trackNum = $(this).index() + 1;
            $('.song:nth-of-type('+trackNum+')').addClass('hover');
        }, function() {
                var trackNum = $(this).index() + 1;
            $('.song:nth-of-type('+trackNum+')').removeClass('hover');
        });
}
```

Any suggestions welcome, thanks for your response!

Comment: `$(window).load(function)` is deprecated, you should use `$(window).on("load", function)`

Comment: Are you sure `OnloadFunction()` isn't running? Put a `console.log` in it and see whether that prints something.

Comment: Thanks, I've made this adjustment though have the same result - it runs on initial page load but not after the ajax is loaded.

Comment: what is inside `OnloadFunction()?`. do you want some eventListeners like `$().on('click')`?. We feed the code from OnloadFunction.

Comment: The `OnloadFunction()` is running but runs too soon - before the html has been updated (console confirms this)

Comment: I've added the contents of the `OnloadFunction()` above. It changes the position of the html just loaded and click events for this content.

Comment: Did you try adding a `console.log("in OnloadFunction")` like I suggested?

Comment: Yes, it ran but before the html was updated

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment:

> The OnloadFunction() is running but runs too soon - before the html
> has been updated

Therefore, I instead suggest placing the calling of `OnloadFunction()` in the `success` callback of your AJAX request *after* the html has been updated like so:

```
success: function(response) {
    $('.all-songs').html(response);
    OnloadFunction();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried both 
`success: function(response) {
            $('.all-songs').html(response);
            OnloadFunction();
        }` 
and
        `complete: function() {
            OnloadFunction();
        }` 
neither are working

Comment: is the post request response returning the expected data?

Comment: I believe this is because the new html is generated in `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {`
which runs a function on html generated from `$('.all-songs').html(response);`

Answer (score 0):

Found a resolution to this - the function needed to be run after the other code in the ajaxComplete rather than in a separate ajaxComplete function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
     xxxxxx
     OnloadFunction();
  });
});
```